# Events on html5 object tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

It seems that trigger/on jQuery events both standard and custom do not work on object tag.

This does **not work**:

```
var $test = $("<object>"); 
$test.on("test", function (){
  console.log("jquery test handler");
});
$test.trigger("test");
```

While it works with other html tags (tried div, video, etc.).

Vanilla js solution works:

```
var test = document.createElement("object");
test.addEventListener("testV", function(e) {
  console.log("vanilla test handler");
 });
var event = new CustomEvent("testV");
test.dispatchEvent(event);
```

jQuery ver. 1.11.1
Tests: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPGoJg

---

**Questions**:

1. Am I only one who has this bug or am I doing something wrong?
2. Is this a jQuery bug or is it expected behaviour?
3. Any workarounds (especially for custom events besides using another element)?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example does not work because the element has not yet been added to the DOM.

```
var $test = $("body").append("<object>"); 
$test.on("test", function (){
  console.log("jquery test handler");
});
$test.trigger("test");
```

You could use alternative JQuery functions to add the element.

Comment: This actually works and might be considered as workaround. Workaround because my first example works with other html tags, but not object.  
Additionally, this works:  
    `var $test = $("<object>");  
    $test = $("body").append($test); 
    ...`   
and this don't:  
    `var $test = $("<object>");  
    $("body").append($test); 
    ...`
Which is quite strange

Answer (score 1):

Update:
First Post was completely wrong however this seems to work for clicking on the object tag

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).on('click', 'object', function(event) {
    console.log("jquery test handler");});
</script>
<object width="400" height="400">Object</object>
```

The important part is `$(document)`
Update 2: More relevant code to the issue using trigger and custom event

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<object>Object</object>
<script>
$(document).on('test', 'object', function(event) {
    console.log("jquery test handler");});
$('object').trigger('test');
</script>
```